# Angular API variable doesn't reflect results in template but does inside ts Class file

Tags: html, angular, data-binding

I am making an API call and that API call successfully returns data which is printed in a console.log

However when I use this same variable in the template, it keeps the default value, which in this case is an empty array.

I'm using generic names for this.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '@app/core/api/mainmenu/data.service';
import { MenuBlockModel } from '@app/core/models/menu-block.model';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-mainmenu',
    templateUrl: './mainmenu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./mainmenu.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class MainmenuComponent implements OnInit {

    public menuBlock: MenuBlockModel = [];
    public dummyString: string = 'This works';
    constructor(
        public DataService: DataService,
    ) {
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.DataService.getData$()
            .subscribe(result => {
                this.menuBlock = result.menuBlocks;
                // Console log displays results
                console.log('this.menuBlock', this.menuBlock);
            });
    }

}
```

And the variable that doesnt display:

```
<html>
    {{menuBlock | json}} // []
    {{menuBlock}} // nothing displayed
    {{dummyString}} // 'This works'
</html>
```

Comment: mh try just {{menuBlock}} or {{menuBlock | json}}

Comment: @ashish.gd This works with ChangeDetectorRef. If you create an Answer, i will mark it as correct. Otherwise i will create it later

Comment: But I see you have edited the question and removed `OnPush`. Are you not using it anymore ?

Comment: @ashish.gd Yes, I had removed it but it did not fix the problem. When you suggested ChangeDetectorRef, I readded it but forgot to update the question. I am still curious as to why the problem persisted after OnPush was removed though.

Comment: Got the issue. In Angular statements between curly `{{}}` braces are simple evaluated as an expression. I am guessing in your case, after removing `onPush` it displayed `[object Object]` for the line `{{menuBlock}}`

Comment: @ashish.gd Removing onPush did not alter the results. Still an empty array for {{menuBlock | json}} and nothing for {{menuBlock}}

Comment: Can you share the code for `getData$()` method ?